# How to access the protected member of print_r s output

Tags: php

The below image comes as result of the code!

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($Number);
    echo "</pre>";
```

The output is [image]

I want to access the `min_number_`  of  `_data:protected` (array);
When I gave like 
`$Number->_data['min_number_']` it shows the error **Cannot access protected property**

```
$Number[_data]['min_number_']
```

also not working.

Comment: 1. You have an object! So use `->` to access properties! 2. If it is protected you need a method to access the property and get the value

Comment: You will need to use reflection

Comment: can you please tell more

Comment: Your question shows that you have a lot to learn about PHP. Much more than we can teach in an answer here. This may be a good place for you to start http://php.net/oop.  In the meantime I am voting to close this question as 'too broad'.

Comment: @Rizier :I tried that also Cannot access protected property error !! echo $Number->_data->min_number_;

Comment: @NMN Did you read my second point?

Comment: check if your object has its own getter method, it might have one

Comment: Hey kindly help me ;please provide me with the links,i tried serialize and un serialize;Serialize gives data in a j son type format ;but then how to access it ?